# AngularUI select2 AJAX set via model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

I'm using AngularUI's `ui-select2` directive with AJAX.

Here's what I've got in my view:

```
<label>Group: <input ng-model="group" ui-select2="select2GroupConfig"></label>
```

Here's what I have in my model:

```
$scope.select2GroupConfig = {
    ajax: {
        url: 'theURL',
        data: function (term, page)
        {
            return { q: term };
        },
        results: function (data, page)
        {
            return { results: data };
        }
    }
};
```

This works as expected.

---

**My question:** How can I update the value via the model?

I tried:

```
$scope.group = 'some group';
```

I also tried using an object:

```
$scope.group = { id: 32, text: 'some group'};
```

but that doesn't either work.

**How do you update a select2 that uses AJAX, via the model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you **can** set it to an object, but only after `ui-select2` runs; I was trying to give it an initial value.

So, instead of using the regular model, you have to use `select2`'s `initSelection` function:

```
$scope.group = 'Dummy Content';

$scope.select2GroupConfig.initSelection = function ( el, fn ) {
    fn({ id: 2, text: 'Some group' });
}
```

Note that you have to give the input an initial value, otherwise `initSelection` is never called. That's why I'm just setting it to some dummy content.

---

This works, but it feels like a hack.

Does anybody have any better ideas?

Comment: "Note that you have to give the input an initial value"

I've seen this comment in lots of places, but how does one go about providing an initial value.  I've tried setting it via ng-model but that doesn't seem to trigger initSelection

Answer (score 0):

If you have `initSelection` setup, you can pass just the ID and the directive will pull up the entire row object.

This will also allow you to set the value when the page loads to just the ID too.

If you don't want to use `initSelection` you can set the entire row (object) as the value and select2 will update accordingly. It all depends on your use-case however.